# How can I make dynamic page view controller with Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uipageviewcontroller, uipangesturerecognizer

I want to make dynamic page view controller.
I want to add a specific page when I do Screen Edge Pan Gesture Recognizing
(from right to left).
Also, I want to move the existing page before I panned.

I know that

```
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?

func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int

func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int
```

are required(for UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource)
How can I make the code with Swift?
I want to know dynamic paging solution.

Comment: What have you tried? If you know the required function delegation methods, you should try something first.

Comment: If you know you're going to use a UIPageViewController, then use it. What's the question?

Comment: I tried to do, so I implemented static page situation. But I don't know the way to code in dynamic page situation.

Comment: The number of pages is not determined.

Comment: Take a look a the function `setViewControllers(_:direction:animated:completion:)` which can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIPageViewController/setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:).

Comment: I want to know good examples. I'm not sure my code.